# New to C - What is this saying?

Tags: c

I came across some code in a header file & I'm unable to figure out what it is trying to say:

```
#define MAP_1 ((unsigned long)0x01) 
#define MAP_2 (MAP_1<<1)        
#define MAP_3 (MAP_1|MAP_2) 
#define MAP_4 (MAP_1<<2)
```

1) is the MAP_1 going to be assigned a fixed value of '1' (why hex?)?

2) is MAP_2 going to be the value of MAP_1 + 1?

3) what is MAP_3 going to be?

Comment: `#define MAP_1 1ul` is c89 style.

Comment: You might like to read about the C-preprocessor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor, bit-shifting (`<<`, `>>`) and bit-wise (`|`) operators.

Comment: Since these `MAP_...` identifiers are indeed preprocessor macros, a better verb in this case might be "defined as" or "replaced" (i.e., occurrences of macros are substituted with their definition in the source file before compiling), instead of "assigned" (e.g., a value to a variable, which is not what's happening here). Respect the preprocessor! Welcome to C (and this site). :)

Answer (score 5):

> Is the MAP_1 going to be assigned a fixed value of '1' (why hex?)?

Yes, it is assigned a value of `1`. Hex is often used to underscore the fact that a certain number if used for its bit pattern, rather than for its numeric value. In this case it is not essential.

> is MAP_2 going to be the value of MAP_1 + 1?

No, it is going to have the value of MAP_1 * 2. The `<<` is a shift left operator. It multiplies by two in binary (to see why, think of shifting a decimal number left by one position).

> what is MAP_3 going to be?

It is going to be `3` - the result of bitwise OR-ing of `2` and `1`.

```
binary 0010 = decimal 2
        OR
binary 0001 = decimal 1
-----------   ---------
binary 0011 = decimal 3
```

Answer (score 1):

- `MAP_1` is 1, hex is arbitrary.
- `MAP_2` is 1 << 1 (bit shift), so the value assigned will be 2 (10 in binary).
- `MAP_3` is 1 | 2 (bit or), so the value is going to be 3 (11 in binary).
- `MAP_4` is 1 << 2, so the value will be 4 (100 in binary).